# Detecting outliers in df

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I have numeric data set with few columns and hundreds of rows, looks similar to this:

```
a   |  b  |  c  |  d
1   |  3  |  .3 |  26
.02 | 32  |  5  |  2.6
```

I am trying to detect outliers using `std`, I found this code:

```
df.a[((df.a - df.a.mean()) / df.a.std()).abs() > 2]
```

Which does what I want for a single column, I would like to be able to do it for whole `df` in a loop maybe? Each column has different `mean` and `std`. It might be something simple but Im quite new to all this. If it is possible to display the outliers in `df` as values and in other cells(no outliers) `Nan` or `0`?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col][((df[col] - df[col].mean()) / df.[col].std()).abs() > 2]
```

Comment: There is a small typo but other than that does what I want, Thanks!!